# Treeview node selection changed after clicking on any potion of the dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, treeview

I have a `treeview` in the left side of the user control and in the same user control there is `dataGridView`. I am simply clicking on the `treeviewnode` and as general it's get selected but just after that when i do mouse down in any portion of the `DataGridView`, i found that the `treenode's` highlighted portion become disappear and it become not selected.

This scenario is not happening with any other control.
How can i disable this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [TreeView.HideSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hideselection(v=vs.110).aspx) property to false:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the selected tree node remains
> highlighted even when the tree view has lost the focus.
>
> When this property is set to false, selected nodes in the TreeView
> control remain highlighted in a different color than the current
> selection color when the TreeView control loses focus. You can use
> this property to keep items that are selected by the user visible when
> the user clicks a different control on the form or moves to a
> different window.

Comment: Is there any solution for color? @Idle_Mind